# Ethernet shield not have MAC address sticker

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, ethernet

Hi everyone I recently bought an Arduino Mega and Arduino Ethernet Shield. There are lots of forum posts that say the shield should have a MAC address that is written on the back side of shield, but I don't have any sticker which has the MAC address. Does anyone know how I can get my MAC address or configure it with a new MAC address? Thanks

Comment: You can set the MAC address to whatever you want. See the above question that yeti mentions.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin), you can just provide your own.

> mac: the MAC (Media access control) address for the device (array of 6 bytes). this is the Ethernet hardware address of your shield. Newer Arduino Ethernet Shields include a sticker with the device's MAC address. For older shields, choose your own.

Comment: YES... you can define a MAC yourself. If you want to do it right, read a bit about MACs, especially the LAA-bit and how not to specify a broadcast address...